# Push two array with key values in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays first array
connections Array

```
[
    {
        account_id: '1000024965925119facebook',
        account_name: 'JijoJohn',
        account_image: '5133_a.jpg',
        account_type: 'facebook'
    },
    {
        account_id: '100002496592511facebook',
        account_name: 'JijoJohn',
        account_image: '55133_a.jpg',
        account_type: 'facebook'
    },
    {
        account_id: '138115932930527facebook',
        account_name: 'JijoJohn',
        account_image: '5555133_a.jpg',
        account_type: 'facebook'
    },
    {
        account_id: '101706396580621facebook',
        account_name: 'JijoJohn',
        account_image: '55133_a.jpg',
        account_type: 'facebook'
    },
    {
        account_id: 'feed1',
        account_name: 'JijoJohn',
        account_image: '5555133_a.jpg'
    },
    {
        account_id: '57880525twitter',
        account_name: 'MinuJose',
        account_image: 'b4_normal.png',
        account_type: 'twitter'
    }
]
```

count Array

```
[
    {
        type: 'facebook',
        count: 4
    },
    {
        type: 'twitter',
        count: 1
    }
]
```

Here am pushing the second array into first array

```
connections.push(count);
```

My requirement is how to add key values in to the joined array like the following way. I need to add accounts and count keys before each array. Please help me to find one solution. Thanks

```
{ 
    "accounts" : 
    [
        {
            account_id: '57880525twitter',
            account_name: 'MinuJose',
            account_image: 'b4_normal.png',
            account_type: 'twitter'
        },
        {
              account_id: '57880525twitter',
            account_name: 'MinuJose',
            account_image: 'b4_normal.png',
            account_type: 'twitter'
        }
    ],
    "count" :
    [

        {
            "type":"facebook",
             "count": 4
        } ,
         {
            "type":"twitter",
            "count": 1
        } 
    ]
}
```

Comment: I think there's something wrong with your data structure. When you call `connections.push(count);` it will not concatenate two arrays, it will just add an array in the end of the array. For instance : `a=[1,2];a.push([3,4]);` will produce `[1,2,[3,4]]`, not `[1,2,3,4]`. Then I'm not sure what kind of data you want to join nor what the result should look like. Maybe you want to add two twitter accounts and update the accounts field of connections and update its count field ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like

```
 var result = {
    accounts: accountsArray,
    counts: countsArray
 }

 (or)

 var result = {
 }
 result.accounts = accountsArray;
 result.counts = countsArray.
```

You do not need `array.push`.

Answer (score 1):

you want to create a new object, not an array:

```
  new_object = {
     "accounts" : account_array,
     "count": count_array
  }
```